# Basis without certain vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I determine a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus U $ with $U = \operatorname{span}\{^t (0,1,1)\}$

I'm looking for three vectors so that I cannot get any vector like $r\cdot  ^t(0,1,1)$ with a linear-combination of those three vectors..

Well, how does this work? :)

Comment: The set $\mathbb R^3\setminus U$ isn't a vector space, it doesn't make sense to talk about a basis for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must be some misinterpretation here, as this question as it stands has not much meaning, because any linearly independent three vectors in $\Bbb R^3$ (i.e. any basis) must span *all* $\Bbb R^3$, including necessarily $U$.

- The most probable version of the original question might refer to the *quotient space* $\Bbb R^3/U$ instead of the set difference $\Bbb R^3\setminus U$ (which is not a linear space anyway, as it is not closed under addition). 
  For the quotient space, extend $b_1:={}^t(0,1,1)$ to a basis in $\Bbb R^3$ with $b_2,b_3$ (say, $b_2:={}^t(1,0,0),\ b_3:={}^t(0,1,0)$ would do it), then the elements $b_2+U$ and $b_3+U$ of the quotient space form a basis for it.
- If you mean that you are looking for a basis $b_1,b_2,b_3$ of $\Bbb R^3$ such that $b_i\notin U$, then it's easy, take the standard basis.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean $\mathbb{R}^3/U$, that is, the quotient vector space, it's rather easy: complete $^t(0,1,1)=v_3$ to a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$, say $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$. Then isn't
$$
\{v_1+U,v_2+U\}
$$
a basis of the quotient space?

Answer (score 1):

Let me see if I can make sense of your question. If you want a space that is orthogonal to $U$ (Orthogonal complement and not set complement) then I would proceed as follows:

Find a basis for $U$, say $[u_1, \cdots u_k]$.

Find a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$. Any basis will do. Let it be $[v_1, v_2, v_3]$.

Now start with the sequence of vectors $[u_1,  \cdots u_k, v_1, v_2, v_3]$.
Apply the Gram-Schmidt process to get $[w_1,w_2,w_3]$. The first $k$ vectors are a basis for $U$ and the remaining are a basis for the complement.

In your case there is only one $u_1 = ^t (0,1,1)$